# Don't know how to handle touches as single entities

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a game for iPad where two different players may interact with the environment at the same time. When the game is played by two people in the same device at once I have a problem that I don't know how to solve. I want the game to behave in the next way: when a player touches a sprite, and finishes the touch in another sprite the app must be able to know that it has been the same player who did it.

What my app does now is the following: suppose that player1 touches a sprite. Then, player2 touches another. Neither of them finishes the touch. Now, player1 ends his touch in a third sprite. But, with the code that I have right now, what it would do is to invoke the function "action" with the second and the third sprite, when I need to pass the first and the third sprite, and I'm freaking out a little because I don't know how to do it. Here's the code you need:

```
var globalReference: Int = 0

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch: UITouch! = touches.first as UITouch!
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    var spriteTouched: Int? = 0

    if self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation).name != nil {
        spriteTouched = Int(self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation).name!)
        globalReference = spriteTouched
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch: UITouch! = touches.first as UITouch!
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    var spriteTouched: Int? = 0
    if self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation).name != nil {
         spriteTouched = Int(self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation).name!){
         if(globalReference != spriteTouched) {
            action1(globalReference, spriteTouched)
         } else {
             action2(globalReference)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The way I get to know what sprite is touched is using ".name" where the name is always an Int. I use the variable globalReference to know what sprite was touched in touchesBegan in touchesEnded, and well, this implementation is what I really don't know how to solve. Consider the rare cases like when you don't touch a sprite solved. 
I would be grateful if someone could help me a little on this…

Thank you!

PS: Yes, I know it is a difficult question… Just a challenge : )

Comment: If player1 touches a sprite then player2 touches a different sprite, I assume your app is detecting this with a delay. Now what if player1 touch a third sprite, how will your app know that player1 is the player that did the touch? if your app knows who touched what then it should know who stop touching what.

Comment: Maybe I haven't explained it properly. There isn't a first touch for the first sprite and then a third one for the third, everything is just one touch, but it has a start (1st sprite) and an end (3rd sprite). What I want is that the whole touch has been started in a sprite (1st one) and it ends in another (3rd one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITouch objects are persistent.  Keep a reference to the name of the sprite found in touchesBegan with the touch.

class property:

```
var touchesToSprites = [UITouch:Int]()
```

in touchesBegan:

```
touchesToSprites[touch] = spriteTouched
```

in touchesEnded:

```
action1( touchesToSprites[touch], spriteTouched )
// remove touchesToSprites[touch] when done
```

Comment: Wow… It looks like it might work. Thank you! When I'll try it I will mark this answer as the correct one as long as it works